# Why is the browser not throwing an error when setting X-Requested-With header when calling another domain?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I am running my server on `localhost`. I tried sending a http request using `fetch` with `cors` mode set as `no-cors`. I sent the request to a random resource in `google.com` domain. This request had the `X-Requested-With` header set to some custom value, save "Foo". This request successfully went through and returned a `404 NOT FOUND` http status code on the browser.
But I expectation was that the request should not have been sent at all and that the browser should have thrown an error instead because on the following headers are allowed to be set cross-domain

```
Accept
Accept-Language
Content-Language
Last-Event-ID
Content-Type
```

Was my expectation wrong?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin the question does not require a reproducible example, IMO.

Comment: I would have figured out the answer a lot faster if there had been one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#headers-class):

> Otherwise, if the context object’s guard is "request-no-cors" and name/value is not a no-CORS-safelisted request-header, return.

Attempting to set `X-Requested-With` fails silently and the request is made **without the header**.